# Accepting two client sockets as a server for a one-on-one game; mistake in tutorial?

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming

I want to add network one-on-one support for my Battleship game, and found this tutorial regarding server-client network programming:

http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-multi-threaded-server-socket.htm

The code I'm using is the following, more or less just taken from there with some adjustments:

```
  public class HandleClient
  {
    TcpClient clientSocket;
    string clientNumber;

    public void StartClient(TcpClient inClientSocket, string clientNumber)
    {
      this.clientSocket = inClientSocket;
      this.clientNumber = clientNumber;

      Thread clientThread = new Thread(DoChat);
      clientThread.Start();
    }

    private void DoChat()
    {
      int requestCount = 0;
      byte[] inBytes = new byte[10025];
      string dataFromClient = null;
      byte[] outBytes = null;
      string rCount;
      string serverResponse = null;

      while (true)
      {
        try
        {
          requestCount++;

          NetworkStream stream = clientSocket.GetStream();
          stream.Read(inBytes, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);

          dataFromClient = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inBytes);
          dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$$"));
          Console.WriteLine(" >> From client " + clientNumber + dataFromClient);

          rCount = Convert.ToString(requestCount);
          serverResponse = "Server to client " + clientNumber + ": " + rCount;
          outBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse);
          stream.Write(outBytes, 0, outBytes.Length);
          stream.Flush();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

and

```
  class BattleshipServer
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8888);
      TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
      int counter = 0;

      serverSocket.Start();

      while (true)
      {
        if (counter < 2)
        {
          counter++;

          clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
          Console.WriteLine("Client " + counter + " connected.");
          HandleClient client = new HandleClient();
          client.StartClient(clientSocket, counter.ToString());
        }
      }

      clientSocket.Close();
      serverSocket.Stop();
      Console.WriteLine(" >> " + "exit");
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
```

However, I wonder about the last few lines just above this. Visual Studio complains about this code being unreachable, and I can see why. Is there any reason behind this code being there?
Also, I wonder what keeps `counter` from going up all the time? Is `serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient()` keeping the program "waiting" until another client connects maybe?

Thanks! And if you know of any other good sources to learn about this, I'll be glad to hear them :) Since I'd still have to adjust the above code by a good lot to make my game "wait" for data from the other player, restrict the player count, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typo in the example (`handleClinet()`) may hint that the code was never reviewed; and you're right, the code won't leave the `while` block in this case.

The counter appears to serve as an identification of each client, as the introduction says "can handle multiple clients at the same time".

In your case, a one-on-one game, you probably want a single `serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient` and start the game after some basic information has been exchanged (ie. player names of both ends communicated), and you won't need that `while` loop there.

Comment: Thank you! I think I'll go the way of accepting two clients though, since the server is a separate console program. This may come in handy should I decide to generalize it to accept more people playing each other later. So the AcceptTcpClient() really "waits" for a connection then?

Comment: @Randal'Thor yes `AcceptTcpClient()` blocks until a client has connected.